# How to dynamically change the combobox values based on another combobox value?

Tags: extjs, extjs4.2, sencha-architect

I have multiple combo boxes which should be inter related. I need to change the combo box values based on a value selected in one combo box.

Say, If I select one Category in combo box, then all the other combo boxes should be getting values which are related to Category.

Please have a look at the table below:

[image]

Comment: you can use store filtering ex: combobox.store.filter(<fieldname>, <filter>)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a lot of values ​​in your combo-box, it's not necessary to early load all.

You can fill them "manually" by a "querymode : local".

So, your query who fill your combo should depends on the others

Answer (score 0):

Each [combobox](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.3/#!/api/Ext.form.field.ComboBox) needs to be assigned a [store](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.3/#!/api/Ext.data.Store) .

In your case, you can create one store with only Categories data and another store with all the data shown in your grid one for each of the dependent combo boxes.

Using [onselect](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.3/#!/api/Ext.form.field.ComboBox-event-select) event listener of Categories dropdown, you can [filter](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.3/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-filter) the stores of the dependent comboboxes.

(If you want to know how to define a combobox and store, you can look at the below example 
http://try.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.1/docs/Ext.form.field.ComboBox.1/
and several others from sencha docs.)